# Бот отправляет без шрифта

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Написал простого телеграмм бота, который повторяет все твои сообщения. Но если ему отправить с жирным шрифтом, то он вернёт без него. Как сделать так, чтобы отправлял с жирным шрифтом тоже?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)
```

Comment: Вы пробывали указать parse_mode = Markdown Это может помочь.

Comment: Да, не сработало

Answer (score 1):

Для форматирования сообщений отправляемых ботом требуется указать `parse_mode`, а так же использовать [синтаксис разметки](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options), например `Markdown`:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '*' + message.text + '*', parse_mode='Markdown')
```